# MediaWiki api - get last changes

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

How can i get the list of all pages, that were changed since some date using mediawiki api?

EDIT: I have already found this query:) F.e. for wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges&rclimit=500&rcnamespace=0

Comment: Note that the query involving `list=recentchanges` is affected by [$wgRCMaxAge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRCMaxAge).

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may help - on the Special:Log page you can see logs from certain year / month. See [Wikipedia's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Log).

This is *not* all changes but only deleted, moved, uploaded and created information.

You can also see all the pages that have *not* been changed using Special:AncientPages ([Wikipedia's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:AncientPages) is not available).

So there are two items which *don't* specifically answer your question but maybe point you (or someone else) in the right direction.